# how to justify $p \equiv q$ if and only if both conditional statements $p \to q$ and $q \to p$ are tautologies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do I justify if this is true or false? I think it's true because I'm pretty sure we could form the contrapositive of a biconditional out of $p \to q$ and $q \to p$, but I don't know how to translate if and only if into logical quantifiers.

Comment: A truth table would be quick

Comment: Depends on how you define things.

Comment: I mean, often $p\equiv q$ is defined as $p\to q\land q\to p$

Comment: What definition of $\equiv$ are you using?

Comment: "p iff q" is exactly "(if p, then q) **and** (if q, then p)".

Comment: Just use the semantics and definitions! Two statements are equivalent iff they always have the same truth-value iff you cannot have one true and the other false

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the axiom of propositional extensionality?
See https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.PropExtensionality.html. If so, you won't prove it.